# Using administrator user to execute a program from C#

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, administrator, process.start

I've got a problem executing a c# code which executes other c# program, it has to open with an administrator user. It works fine in windows 8 but when i want to execute it in windows 10 it says that the user or password is wrong. Maybe, the way you log in  windows 8 is  differently with win 10. In this following code you will have to change it to open a document or image(as you wish) the thing is that you have to open it with cmd and the administrator user.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using System.DirectoryServices;
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Security;
   namespace Ejecutable
 {
  static class Program
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Punto de entrada principal para la aplicación.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {  

      string cmdPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "cmd.exe");
            string workingDirectory = @"C:\Users\Desktop";
            string pathToFile = Path.Combine(workingDirectory, "distri2017.pdf");
            string arguments = string.Format("/c start {0}", pathToFile);
            var password = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "password")
                password.AppendChar(c);
            var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = cmdPath,
                Arguments = arguments,
                WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
                UserName = "ADMINISTRATOR",
                Domain = Environment.MachineName, // Could use domain
               Password = password,
                UseShellExecute = false,
            };
            Process.Start(processStartInfo);


        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("COULDNT OPEN: "+e);
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: More than likely Windows UAC setting is set differently between the two operating systems.

Comment: Don't use the "Administrator" account (RID 500) to code like it's 1999. It's disabled by default, for good reason. If you're legitimately doing system administrative work, then `UseShellExecute` should be `true` and the `Verb` should be "runas" to prompt the user for consent to elevate. OTOH, if the normal operation of a non-administration program requires admin access, then it needs to be redesigned to work when run as a standard user.

Comment: Working directory `C:\Users\Desktop` is also wrong. Such a directory does not exist by default on any Windows.